# MongoDb large array in field vs. many small documents with one array item each

Tags: mongodb

I have a question about how to store some simple data in mongoDb that happens to be large and vary in size regularly.

I want to store all of the threadIds from each of my users Inbox's.

The threadIds are strings that look like "168849c793fa996a".  It may be common that a user has 10,000+ (~400KB) or even occasionally as many as 50,000+(~2MB) worth of threadIds.

My app assists in clearing out the Inbox (deleting and sorting messages)

I will be using the information to know what the current state of a users Inbox is, i.e. what messages have been removed and what new ones have arrived.

The array will therefore be updated semi-frequently and it's size may significantly change on each update.

This leaves me with two ideas on how to store the data

1. If I store documents like this:

   ```
   {
     _id: ObjectID,
     userId: String,
     threadIds: [String]
   }
   ```

a. It will be easy to query the array of threadIds with db.collection.findOne().

b. It will be easy to update with db.collection.updateOne() (or perhaps db.collection.deleteOne() and db.collection.insertOne() to avoid the large fluctuations in document size).

However...

c. I have read that it is not good for the db to have docs that change in size radically on such a scale

d. my experience is that an array with 10,000+ Strings in it can make Compass hang for ~10-15 seconds if there are a few documents of that size on the page and hang for 20-30 seconds if there is an attempt to view the array within a document that contains it. (*Although my app itself loads the data very fast when findOne() is called*).

2. If I store documents like this :

   ```
   {
     _id: ObjectID,
     userId: String,
     threadId: String
   }
   ```

a. It will be easy to get an array of all threadIds back by querying with db.collection.find().distinct({ userId: userId }) with an index on userId.

b. This seems to be more inline with the mongoDb way of many smaller documents and is much friendlier within the Compass user interface.

However...

c. It will be slightly harder to update the information because I will have to use db.collection.deleteMany() and db.collection.insertMany() on every update.

d. This would add a small to medium amount of extra complexity to my app.

Given the size of the data held in the array fluctuating between ~5KB and 2MB but also the fact that I will likely always need the entire array every time I query for it. What is the best (most "correct") way that I can represent, store, and update this data?

Comment: The third, hybrid approach appears to inherit worst characteristics of the other two :) It's even more complicated to write. And now it's (more) complicated to read too (you'd have to merge these docs at some point, to have a flat view. Or maybe not). If I were to implement this, I'd start with option 2

Comment: thanks, I just wrote this so that 3rd one was a bit of a reach/brain storm ;-) ...it has been removed.